# pknfc jpasskit,pass not getting opened with ios

Tags: java, android, ios, nfc, passkit

I am trying to generate a ios pass.Once i remove code of nfc

```
PKStoreCard storeCard = new PKStoreCard();
storeCard.setPrimaryFields(primaryFields);
PKNFC nfc = new PKNFC();
                nfc.setMessage("DUMMY_14589"); // account RFID -- DUMMY_XXXXXX
                nfc.setEncryptionPublicKey("properkey="); // GREENLOTS.NFC_PUBLIC_KEY
```

I am unable to open the pass.once i remove this i am able to access my pkpass file.
Can you Please suggest ,If i am missing out on something
Regards
Mayanka